# Как передать список List с 1 класса в другой?

Tags: java, android

Есть активити при нажатии на кнопку в другом классе через AsyncTask я получаю данные с базы  и записываю в `List lst = new ArralList<>();Как  этот список мне передать в активити ??? можно ли как то наследоваться от списка ?

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно в `AsyncTask` передавать список, который используется в активити и менять его в `AsyncTask`'е. Учитывая, что в Java ( => и в Android) всё есть ссылка, список, переданный в `AsyncTask` будет тем же списком, что используется в `Activity`

Comment: Сможете показать пример реализации .Мне нужно из  AsynsTasa передать в Activity

Comment: есть другие пути для передачи списка из потока asyntask в активити?

Comment: @elik, ты имеешь ввиду, уведомления активити об изменениях в списке?

Comment: У меня по сути 2 класса активити

Comment: один MainActivity воторой класс наследуется об AsynTask

Comment: Я хочу после работы в потоке передать список со значениями в 1 класс.

Comment: Верно я понимаю, что вы делаете что-то в `MainActivity`, открывается второе активити, что-то происходит и после отработки второго активити (его завершения) - мы возвращаемся в первое активити и там список должен измениться?

Comment: дааааа!главное во 2 активити все ок данные получаются но затем в 1 активити показыавет что размер списка 0

Comment: как правильно передать данные из Asyntask а в активити ю

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/69-urok-30-podrobnee-pro-onactivityresult-zachem-nuzhny-requestcode-i-resultcode.html). По сути, в `onPostExecute`-методе `AsyncTask` вам нужно будет создать Intent, в который положить ваш список, а в `MainActivity` в методе `onActivityResult` этот список доставать и вызывать методы обновления.

Comment: А почему не срабатывает передача путем конструктора ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58502/discussion-between-a-ovsyannikov-and-elik).

Answer (score 1):

Для `AsyncTask` добавляете как параметр в конструктор `List`:

```
CustomAsyncTask(List targetList, ...) {
    this.targetList = targetList;
}
```

Затем в активити при создании этого `AsyncTask`'а передаёте ему этот список. Для изменения списка можно использовать `List#add` и иже с ним. Если не знаете, как сделать обновление по изменению в активити, можно после изменений списка сделать `targetList.notifyAll()`, а в Activity создать поток, который будет ожидать этого события для `targetList`